# Mysql trigger syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, debugging, triggers

I have a very large file that creates triggers that I auto generated. However I'm not able to get passed line 3.

Php version 5.3.2
Mysql Version 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41

Here are the first few lines:

```
  1  delimiter $$
  2  -- CompanyTitleHolder
  3  -- Create INSERT event for CompanyTitleHolder
  4  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_insert_CompanyTitleHolder AFTER INSERT ON CompanyTitleHolder 
  5  FOR EACH ROW
  6  BEGIN
  7
  8  IF(NEW.CompanyTitleHolderID <> '') OR (NEW.CompanyTitleHolderID IS NOT NULL) THEN
  9    CALL add_Audit (@UserName, "CompanyTitleHolder", "CompanyTitleHolderID", "--new record--", NEW.CompanyTitleHolderID);
 10  END IF;
 11 -- This goes on for quite a while
 ?? END;$$
 ?? delimiter ;
```

And this is the error:

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER trigger_insert_CompanyTitleHolder AFTER INSERT ON CompanyTitleHolder  F' at line 3 */
```

I'm trying to do an audit table using [this method and code](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=7252) as my base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `OR REPLACE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE OR REPLACE` doesn't seem to work in MySQL, it's an [Old Bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19241). You'll have to do a `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS` before your `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Comment: Thank you :)   No more headaches for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't `CREATE OR REPLACE`.

Try:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_insert_CompanyTitleHolder;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_CompanyTitleHolder AFTER INSERT ON CompanyTitleHolder 
...
```